# Java - Executable JAR? Easy Decompiling?

Tags: java

I recently started with Java and besides the variables, logical operators, loops and stuff like that I played around with JFrames and there are a couple of questions that comes to my mind.

1. I noticed that by saving my program as a `executable jar` the
   program appears to be 1 file. Is that means when you're going to
   develop a something that will use a many resources (images, audio
   files & etc) they will be all stored in this jar file?
2. The second thing I noticed is that I can extract the `jar` file and decompile the `.class` files fairly easy. With that in mind let's say I use a `MySQL` database and to connect to the `MySQL` server I have to do it using `JDBC` driver and I ?must? hardcode the password?
3. Is `Java` suitable for 3D games? I'm really far from this, but let me know. I saw games written with a `Java` 3D game engine like `jMonkeyEngine` and I'm impressed, but I red (read) posts around that `Java` is slow and not that suitable for `3D` games which leaved me a little bit confused.

Comment: Never hardcode a password. And don't expose the database either.

Comment: 3. Game Example: Minecraft was written with Java

Comment: You're going to give yourself an aneurysm if you're just learning java basics and are worrying about 3D programming, bundling and other topics. Stick with learning the basics first. Once your comfortable with that, move on to more advanced topics. If you're concerned about time investment with the ultimate goal of 3D game design, don't be. You'll learn valuable skills that can be ported to C/C++ or other programming languages.

Comment: @booleanCube True, but it runs much slower than many other games, at least on my computer.

Comment: Java runs on the Java Virtual Machine to make it platform independent.  This increases increase its portability but also increases its overhead when performing graphical operations.  It can be done just as @booleanCube's example with Minecraft however it will not be at the highest performance than than other languages that are built more towards performance and less towards portability.

Comment: @RobertH - I think the way the question is written suggests that the OP has a good perspective about what he knows and when to worry about advanced concepts.  I would further infer that this is not his first foray into programming and he's not a 15 year old kid who wants to make a video game overnight (though I agree with everything you've said).

Comment: @jahroy I never said they didn't, nor did I intend to imply anything about age, I simply gave my advice to someone new with programming Java. How fast they move from basic to advanced concepts is up to them. Keep in mind that that all advice may, or may not apply to everyone. Take it for what you will.

Comment: @RobertH - My intent is to compliment the OP, not to disagree with what you said.  I think your advice is spot on.  All I meant was that the OP seems to have a healthy curiosity rather than premature concerns.  Sorry if that came out wrong...

Comment: @jahroy No worries :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can do that, if you want. In Oracle's Java Tutorials you can read about creating executable JAR files: [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)
2. Any kind of program written in any language can be reverse engineered, so regardless of whether it's Java or not, you should never hard-code passwords. With Java byte code it's fairly easy to decompile.
3. More than 10 years ago, when Java was still young, it was relatively slow compared to languages that are compiled to native code directly such as C or C++. However, many advances have been made in the Java virtual machine over the years, and the performance of Java programs is comparable to C++ in many cases. People who still complain that Java is slow aren't up to date or don't have a lot of current experience with Java. Java is certainly fast enough, as you saw from demos with jMonkeyEngine. However, for commercial 3D graphics games, C++ seems to be the traditional de-facto programming language that's used. Note that to squeeze the last bit of performance out of the hardware, you'll need to write code specifically for that hardware. Java isn't the right tool for that, as it's designed to be platform-independent.

Answer (score 2):

1. That is an option.  It's certainly not mandatory, you can load resources from external files as well.
2. That's true.  The common architecture for such an application is to put an application server in between the clients and the actual database.  The application server that you control is what knows the database password.  It only exposes to the clients the operations that they are supposed to be allowed to perform.
3. Minecraft is written in java, so QED.  You won't likely be pushing the limits of modern GPU performance with a game written in Java, but that isn't the goal of every game.

Comment: Games utilizing LWJGL can easily push GPU to the limits as it allows access to OpenGL through Java. Minecraft uses LWJGL btw.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can put everything in one jar
2. Yes, but giving untrusted users raw access to database is rarely a good idea anyway. The better way is to build an server app with public API and authenticate users.
3. It depends. If you want to write an 3d app focused on rich, high-quality graphic effects than Java is probably not the best choice. However 3d in Java is easy and quite high-level, so you save lot of time on development compared to other lower-level technologies.